# Read dox,docx files with the same style

Tags: c#, text, colors, ms-word

I use below code for read doc,docx files and show them in richtextbox but this way can't show files with the same style.for example if text is with red color richtextbox show it with black color
what should i do ?

```
 Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application app = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.ApplicationClass();
        object nullobj = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
        object file = openFileDialog1.FileName;

        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document doc = app.Documents.Open(ref file, ref nullobj, ref nullobj, ref nullobj, ref nullobj, ref nullobj, ref nullobj, ref nullobj, ref nullobj, ref nullobj, ref nullobj, ref nullobj, ref nullobj, ref nullobj, ref nullobj, ref nullobj);

        doc.ActiveWindow.Selection.WholeStory();
        doc.ActiveWindow.Selection.Copy();
        IDataObject data = Clipboard.GetDataObject();
        string text = data.GetData(DataFormats.Text).ToString();
        Console.WriteLine(text);
        doc.Close(ref nullobj, ref nullobj, ref nullobj);
        app.Quit(ref nullobj, ref nullobj, ref nullobj);

        richTextBox1.Text = text;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are out of luck in this case.

Richtextbox is nowhere near as powerful as Word. If it were, everybody would make copies of Word and MS would loose money.

You may get it working partially (like you did). But never good enough.

Comment: I just want to open doc files in it

Comment: There is no "just". Doc is a complicated format. How will your richtextbox handle pages? or Headers and Footers? Your best bet is to just open Word and display document there.

Comment: C# is a language. In the .NET framework? NO. You may find some commercial components for this purpose.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you look at something like [Telerik's](http://www.telerik.com) RadRichTextBox which can read properly handle .docx (and I think .doc) files.  Otherwise you are going to have to convert the data to something the RichTextBox control can understand (in which you'll lose a lot of features).